# Soma entre linhas MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estou com problema em realizar uma operação utilizando MySQL, na verdade nem sei se é possível fazer o que quero.

Tenho uma tabela controle_de_estoque, nesta tabela tenho todas as operações que são realizados com produtos.

Em controle_de_estoque tenho uma coluna chamada tipoMovimentacao que é 1 para entrada e 0 para saída;
o que quero fazer é o seguinte:

```
select * sum(quantidade) from controle_de_estoque where tipoMovimentacao = 0 MENOS select * sum(quantidade) from controle_de_estoque where tipoMovimentacao = 0
```

ou seja, quero subtrair um pelo outro porem tudo que tento da erro.

Alguém sabe o que posso fazer?

Obrigado.

Comment: vai da 0 do jeito que esta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com uma única consulta você poderá obter o saldo se condicionar a soma para cada tipo de movimentação.

Total de entradas - Total de saídas

Veja:

```
select sum(case when tipoMovimentacao = 1 then quantidade else 0 end) 
       - sum(case when tipoMovimentacao = 0 then quantidade else 0 end)
from controle_de_estoque
```

Realizando uma única consulta ao banco você terá uma melhor performance. O custo é praticamente a metade do que realizar dois `select sum()`.

Comment: Opa, bem isso que eu tava procurando. Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
 select   
 (select * sum(quantidade) from controle_de_estoque where tipoMovimentacao = 0)  
 -  
 (select * sum(quantidade) from controle_de_estoque where tipoMovimentacao = 1) as ESTOQUEATUAL   
from dual
```

Assim é para funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um case, se sua intenção e subtrair o a quantidade entre os tipos, não tem como você fazer para todos os campos como você usou no seu script

> select * sum(

```
select * ,
    case whan tipoMovimentacao = 0 then sum(quantidade) end
    -
    case when tipoMovimentacao = 1 then sum(quantidade) end
from controle_de_estoque
```

ou um sub select.

```
 select   
 (select sum(quantidade) from Products where tipoMovimentacao = 0)  
 -  
 (select sum(quantidade) from controle_de_estoque where tipoMovimentacao = 1)
```